# Using ArrayList or HashMap for better speed

Tags: java, performance, arraylist, hashmap

I need a 'List' or 'Map',... of object A. This list will be added from another ArrayList. Object A is considered to be equal to another when `id` parameter of A equals.

My problem is I only want add an object that does not exist in my List. I wonder between the two alternatives for implementation. Using ArrayList or HashMap

```
1. ArrayList:

for (A a: source) {if (! (a in ArrayList)) addToArrayList();}

2. HashMap <id, A>

for (A a: source) {hasmap.put (a.id, a)}
```

Which will give better speed to add a large number (over 1000 objects, or bigger number of object)
Is there a better pattern for my problem???

Comment: Why dont you test it?

Comment: I want to know if have any better pattern for my problem

Comment: If you only want to insert items that aren't already in the collection, why not use a `Set`?

Comment: Often, certain programmers spend too much time addressing performance problems that don't yet exist.  If your application spends only a fraction of its time accessing your data in this way then, frankly, the implementation of HashMap or ArrayList may not even matter one iota.  The only way anybody can say that this detail is important for performance is by profiling your application.

Comment: @scottb While I 100% agree with your first sentence, picking the the right data structure (and related, right collection interface)  does not fall into category of premature optimizations. Trying to first find and then fix a reason for a big application being slow is often a big task. And that O(n*n) is a bitch when n grows in production use.

Comment: This is a great question and it prompted the perfect answer.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

First, I'm going to go out on a limb and state that these are **two completely different data structures.**   A `List` deals with a linear representation of elements, and a `Map` deals with key-pair values.

My gut feeling is that you're attempting to choose between a `List` and a `Set`.

If you wish to only enter *unique* elements, or to put it more succinctly, if you only care about unique values, then a `Set` of some kind is your best bet - probably `HashSet` if you don't care about ordering.  [It provides O(1) time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) for the basic operations, such as add, remove, contains, and size.

<sup>(Interestingly enough, `HashSet` is backed by a `HashMap`, but provides an interface similar to `ArrayList`.)</sup>

Comment: @Makoto Isn't HashMap is backed by a HashSet?

Comment: Bonus: Java has [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) which iterates in insertion order like lists.

Answer (score 66):

The `ArrayList` has O(n) performance for every search, so for n searches its performance is O(n^2).

The `HashMap` has O(1) performance for every search (on average), so for n searches its performance will be O(n).

While the `HashMap` will be slower at first and take more memory, it will be faster for large values of n.

The reason the `ArrayList` has O(n) performance is that every item must be checked for every insertion to make sure it is not already in the list. We will do n insertions,  so it is O(n^2) for the whole operation.

The reason the `HashMap` has O(1) performance is that the hashing algorithm takes the same time for every key and then the lookup to find the key also takes constant time. There can be occasions when the hash table exceeds its load factor and needs to be reallocated, and that it why it is constant *on avarage*.

So finally, to answer your question, my advice is to use the `HashMap`.

Comment: And as @Chris Hayes mentioned, Set(HashSet) is a better solution???. I think Set has the same performance with ArrayList??

Comment: `Set` is an interface. `HashSet` is an implementation that will overall perform better here. `TreeSet` will perform between the two, but guarantee order on top of uniqueness.

Comment: @JohnGaughan nitpick clarification: TreeSet guarantees natural order. LinkedHashSet guarantees insertion order.

Comment: I believe the ArrayList considerations are quite inaccurate, from the documentation: "The size, isEmpty, get, set, iterator, and listIterator operations run in constant time. The add operation runs in amortized constant time, that is, adding n elements requires O(n) time. All of the other operations run in linear time (roughly speaking). The constant factor is low compared to that for the LinkedList implementation."
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: @Stefano ... and for each insert the OP wants to ensure it's unique, requiring the whole ArrayList to be traversed.

Comment: I have for example, 1000 objects with a key for each as a member variable. Which way is more efficient or has less time complexity and space complexity : using a Arraylist of objects or using Hashmap of objects with object's key as Hashmap key?

Comment: @Arash This answer is about the specific conditions stated in the question. To answer your new question you'll need to state whether the keys are unique, and what is the use case. One case is where inserts are rare and lookups are frequent. Another case is where inserts and lookups are similar in number. And another case is where inorder traversal is required. An finally, you have to decide what you mean by *efficient*. If your question matches this one then this is your answer. But if your question is different then check the related questions and do a search to see if your question exists.